# Which of the response is faster? voice or hand action?

Tags: brain, neurophysiology, muscles, psychology

After taking certain stimuli and making the the decision to do certain action, which one response (output) (out of 2 possible output-ways, voice and hand-movement) would act faster?

For example lets say I'm playing a car video game that can be controlled by voice.

If i say "left" it will turn left and so on.

If I'm controlling that car by hand then I could just steer to the left.

So, if i'm not considering energy required for hand to move and all.

Which will get the signal to my brain faster, my mouth or my hand?

Comment: The title and concluding sentence don't seem to match: is your question which output is faster (title) or which stimulus is registered quicker by the brain (last sentence)?

Comment: Which output is faster, using voice or hand?

Comment: Maybe it is hand action for me.

Comment: This question is not a bad question. why it received so little attention

Comment: You could also ask a related question in [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that we are talking about a situation at the physical limit of the brain:

Speaking a word will always be slower than pushing a button.
A whole word requires a contraction of the diaphragm to push out air so this air can be modulated by another sequence of contractions and relaxations of the vocal chords.

So contracting finger muscles is very similar to speech **initiation** however for a computer to respond (in the example you were playing a video game) the computer needs to recognize the full word and then map it to an output before actually implementing the left turn.

So adding the extra processing time of the computer and the actual extra production time of the vocalization you're better off pushing buttons.

As a matter of curiosity if the physical limit situation is relaxed; whenever there is a mismatch in both sensory receptors as well as outputs, the brain does its best to compensate. Think of something dropping on your foot, the visual information is actually delayed so that the sensory stream (that has to go up all of your leg and spine) catches up.